# How to pass payload via JSON file for curl?

Tags: json, curl

I can successfully create a place via `curl` executing the following command:

```sh
$ curl -vX POST https://server/api/v1/places.json -d "
  auth_token=B8dsbz4HExMskqUa6Qhn& \
  place[name]=Fuelstation Central& \
  place[city]=Grossbeeren& \
  place[address]=Buschweg 1& \
  place[latitude]=52.3601& \
  place[longitude]=13.3332& \
  place[washing]=true& \
  place[founded_at_year]=2000& \
  place[products][]=diesel& \
  place[products][]=benzin \
"
```

The server returns `HTTP/1.1 201 Created`.
Now I want to store the payload in a JSON file which looks like this:

```js
// testplace.json
{
  "auth_token" : "B8dsbz4HExMskqUa6Qhn",
  "name" : "Fuelstation Central",
  "city" : "Grossbeeren",
  "address" : "Buschweg 1",
  "latitude" : 52.3601,
  "longitude" : 13.3332,
  "washing" : true,
  "founded_at_year" : 2000,
  "products" : ["diesel","benzin"]
}
```

So I modify the command to be executed like this:

```sh
$ curl -vX POST http://server/api/v1/places.json -d @testplace.json
```

This fails returning `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`. Why?

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you're uploading binary files, you should use `--data-binary`.

Comment: For anyone referencing this question for an answer to 'how do I specify the file that contains the JSON', note that it's with the `@` sign as given in the question e.g. `$ curl -vX POST http://server/api/v1/places.json -d @testplace.json`. This assumes that you are running curl from the directory that contains testplace.json - otherwise use e.g `@/some/directory/some.json`

Answer (score 450, accepted):

`curl` sends POST requests with the default content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you want to send a JSON request, you will have to specify the correct content type header:

```
$ curl -vX POST http://server/api/v1/places.json -d @testplace.json \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

But that will only work if the server accepts json input. The `.json` at the end of the url may only indicate that the *output* is json, it doesn't necessarily mean that it also will handle json *input*. The API documentation should give you a hint on whether it does or not.

The reason you get a `401` and not some other error is probably because the server can't extract the `auth_token` from your request.

Comment: I was trying to use `cat file.json` after the `-d` and was having trouble with it, until I learned from this answer that I can use `@file.json`. Thanks :)

Comment: note that if you need multiple headers you need to specify `-H`/`--header` multiple times, at least when tested in bash on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

To clarify how to actually specify a *file* that contains the JSON to post, note that it's with the `@` sign as shown in the OP

e.g. a typical post to a local .NET Core API:

`curl -X POST https://localhost:5001/api -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/some/directory/some.json`

Answer (score 4):

You can `cat` the contents of a `json` file to `curl` via the `--data-raw` parameter

`curl https://api.com/route -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "$(cat ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | grep -v '^\s*//')"`

`curl https://api.com/route -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @<(jq . ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json)`

`curl https://api.com/route -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @<(jq '{"payload": .}' < ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json)`

Note: comments in the json file are filtered out via `grep -v '^\s*//'`

You can also pass the data to `curl` via `stdin` using `grep` or `cat` or `jq`

`grep -v '^\s*//' ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | curl https://api.com/route -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-`

`cat ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | grep -v '^\s*//' | curl https://api.com/route -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-`

`jq . ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | curl https://api.com/route -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-`

`jq '{"payload": .}' < ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | curl https://api.com/route -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-`