# How to insert JSON from file into POST request for CURL

Tags: bash, http, curl

I am trying to send POST request to server using `curl`. I am trying to add string from file in body of request, but something is wrong.

Example of request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"property_1":"value_1", "property_2":"value_2", "property_3":"'$(cat file.json)'"}' 
    http://localhost:8000/update
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Try adding double quotes around `"$(cat file.json)"`

Comment: You also need a backslash before the second newline so the URL is part of the `curl` command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass payload via JSON file for curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611903/how-to-pass-payload-via-json-file-for-curl)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with tripleee - you likely have characters in the file confusing your CLI and need to quote the output.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"property_1":"value_1", "property_2":"value_2", "property_3":"'"$(<file.json)"'"}' \
    http://localhost:8000/update
```

As an aside, I personally prefer to avoid continuation lines, and will usually use vars and arrays instead for readability and ease of maintenance.

```
boilerplate='"property_1":"value_1","property_2":"value_2","property_3":"'
args=( -X POST 
       -H "Content-Type: application/json"
       -d "{$boilerplate$(<file.json)\"}"
)
curl "${args[@]}" http://localhost:8000/update
```

which results in (effectively)

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"property_1":"value_1","property_2":"value_2","property_3":"<your file stuff>"}' http://localhost:8000/update
```